# Uncommon word describing India

Tags: vocabulary

I am looking for an uncommon word describing India. So far I came up with "diversity", but I fear this is too common.

Just to give a bit background to my question I am a grammarian at a Toastmasters and I just came back from the trip to India. For those who do not know Toastmasters, a grammarian role is to look for correct and incorrect use of language in the speeches and to introduce a word of the day. An uncommon word that should expand a vocabulary of meeting participants.

This is my first question on the English Language & Use. Apologies if this is inappropriate for this exchange.

Comment: Hey data geek! Welcome to EL&U, probably a great place to hang out given your role in Toastmasters. Unfortunately, the StackExchange model as a whole (not just here) breaks down in the face of subjective or option-based questions, so we can't really answer them. That said, one thing you might find helpful is the "[Visual Thesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com)", which is just what it sounds like: you can use it to explore words and their connections to others until you find one that suits. Very helpful if you're not quite sure what you're looking for. Hope that helps, and good luck.

Comment: Apparently, _bombilating_ is a synonym for (at least the literal sense of) _buzzing_. If you can get someone to speak on Greenland, surely _mallemaroking_ has to be worked in somehow.

Comment: I'd suggest "polyglot".

Comment: @DanBron, thanks for the warm welcome. This question definitely helped me and the yesterday toastmasters went great. What would you suggest I do with this question? Should I delete it or maybe it would be possible to make it more objective?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multicultural. A potpourri of people. A mélange of multiculturalism. A concatenation of cultures. A pasticcio of peoples (or people groups). A varietal country. A case study in cultural anthropology.

Comment: +1 Don! I was sure I was gonna win this one, but it appears your "*mélange*"--a term Paul Atreides/Muad'dib would also have appreciated—was just the right spice for OP's curry.

Comment: @LittleEva: Paul who? Don't make me google this early in the morning! Besides, it's six degrees below zero in Pittsburgh today. Geesh.

Comment: Sounds like just the kind of day to stay inside and google.

Answer (score 2):

> **[multifarious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multifarious)** - > 
>    of many and various kinds.
>
> - having or occurring in great variety :  diverse
>     (M-W)

Consisting of a number of [different kinds](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/multifarious) as in :
assorted, diverse, heterogeneous, motley, multiform, varied, variegated, **[ethnic mosaic.](http://www.everyculture.com/Africa-Middle-East/Introduction-to-the-Middle-East-The-Ethnic-Mosaic.html)** (TFD)

Answer (score 2):

**RECHERCHE**

> /rəˌSHerˈSHā,rəˈSHerˌSHā/ *adjective*
>
> rare, exotic, or obscure.
>   "a few linguistic terms are perhaps a bit recherché for the average readership"
>
> *synonyms*: obscure, rare, esoteric, abstruse, arcane, recondite, exotic, strange, unusual, unfamiliar, out of the ordinary
>
> [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=rech+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=recherche+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0i7i30l5.0.0.1.1076175...........0.4vzaKxMn43A&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 1):

[rainbow](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rainbow?s=t): a wide variety or range; gamut; having a diverse membership; including representatives from multiple racial and ethnic groups

[manifold](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/manifold): of many kinds; numerous and varied

Answer (score -1):

> [India](http://www.yourarticlelibrary.com/language/essay-on-linguistic-diversity-in-india/4030/) is a land of many tongues and has been called “as a tower of **veritable** languages” or a “Museum of languages”.